# Shell implementation: signal handling: Any way to return early from wait()?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, signals

I'm doing a shell project for my operating systems class and we're up to the part of doing signal handling. The assignment asks us to catch `SIGINT` and `SIGTSTP`and send the signals to the child process. Here's what I've got so far. If you encounter an undefined variable or function, I hope you can understand its meaning based on the identifier:

```
char input[ MAX_INPUT ];

sigset_t sig;
pid_t *suspendedChildren = NULL;
int nSuspendedChildren = 0;
pid_t currentChild = 0;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{    
  char quit = 0;

  setup();

  do
  {
  getInput();
  quit = handleInput( input );
  } while( quit != EXIT_NUMBER );

  return 0;
}

void setup( void )
{
  // block the interrupt signal 
  sigaddset( &sig, SIGINT);
  sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &sig, NULL);

  // handle the suspend signal
  signal( SIGTSTP, suspendChild );
}

void suspendChild( int signal )
{
  if (currentChild) // meaning that there is a child process currently running
  {
    // increment suspended children counter
    nSuspendedChildren++;

    // reallocate the array of suspended children
    suspendedChildren = (pid_t *)realloc( suspendedChildren, nSuspendedChildren*sizeof(pid_t));
    suspendedChildren[nSuspendedChildren-1] = currentChild;

    // send suspend signal to child
    kill( currentChild, SIGTSTP );

    printf( "\n[%d]+ Stopped\t\t", nSuspendedChildren );
    puts( input );
    putchar( '\n' );

    // set the global to 0
    currentChild = 0;

    main( 0, NULL );
  }
}

int handleInput( char *s )
{
  // string tokenizing / parsing...
  // checks for redirection / background process requests
  // (not relevant to question being asked so omitted)

  currentChild = fork();
  if (currentChild) // parent process
  {
    wait( &status );
  }
  else // child process
  {
    execvp( prgm, tokens );
  }
}
```

So to handle `SIGINT`, I simply block the signal so the child process (the executed command) receives it while the parent process (the shell) ignores it. This works perfectly fine, but it's `SIGTSTP` and the suspension of a process where I'm having trouble. For this signal, I opted to call a signal handler upon its arrival. This works rather nicely since I believe the default `SIGTSTP` handling behavior of processes is to suspend, but since my shell is waiting (see `wait(&status)`) for the child process to return (which is currently suspended), my entire terminal is left in a zombie state. I can't ctrl+D out and I just have to kill the window and log back in...

So to reiterate the title of this post, is there any way to return early from `wait(int*)` from a signal handler? I've looked up documentation and came across this statement:

> wait also returns if a signal is received and is not ignored.

However, that's all it says and provides no further insight.

Comment: Slightly cryptic hint because it is school work: Instead of `wait` consider whether it is really `waitpid` (with a certain option) that you really want to use.

Comment: Why for heavens sake are you calling `main()` from the `SIGTSTP`-signal handler?!

Comment: @alk heh, it was my quick and dirty solution to getting the prompt back after the suspension...

Comment: @Duck thank you very much for the hint! it was foolish of me not to explore the alternative wait() system calls...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `wait` consider whether it is really `waitpid` (with a certain option) that you really want to use. – Duck